# New to linux, installed ubuntu by crouton onto hp chromebook... need help

Tags: 18.04, hp, chromebook, crouton, chromeos

So I installed Ubuntu to use on my Chromebook by Crouton. I am using the Gnome shell because this is what I am learning in class. My problem is, I cannot upgrade it and am stuck at 16.04.6. I do not have much in the way of apps, to include an update manager. I installed my class version onto a virtual machine on another laptop but really want to use this Chromebook. The versions are not the same, that much is apparent just by looking at the windows and such. Is there a way to update it to 18.04? I tried the `sudo apt-get update` command from the terminal but had no luck, nothing was upgraded and nothing was installed. Please help

Comment: `do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I just tried these, the "sudo apt-get update" fetched 218 KB. the "sudo apt-get upgrade" didn't seem to change anything, and "do-release-upgrade" came up with "command not found." I did not mention earlier I installed this via crouton. Really have no clue if this makes a difference.

Comment: Here is a link to the article I used to install it.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview